# Ajax Error!!! parsererror in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a local install of WP running on MAMP.

It is the latest 3.8.

I have installed a theme called Dante which is a pro theme and recommends various plugins (some of which are essential).
One of the plugins in called Revolution slider, and this is giving me grief.

I can install the plugin fine, however when I try and create new slider (from within the plugin) I get a message saying Ajax Error!!! parsererror

I have contacted the plugin supplier who have asked me to check the permissions of the plugin folder - I did (even made them 777) but no joy.

Can anyone help me as to where I should start debugging?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lay with there not being enough memory allocated.

Adding
`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '240M');`
to wp-config fixed it.